# Как создать get и set в функции-конструкторе?

Tags: javascript

Обычно в объектах get или set объявляют так:

```
var obj = {
    get name() {
        return "Name";
    }
};
```

Можно через дескриптор:

```
var obj = {};

Object.defineProperty(obj, "name", {

  get: function() {
    return "Name";
  }
});
```

В конструкторах используют обычный метод(функцию) у который первое слово `get`, `set` или же делают [единый метод](https://learn.javascript.ru/getters-setters#%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80), но как создать обычный `get`, `set` - не знаю.

Comment: Похоже, то что вы хотите реализуемо только в ES6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222209/getter-setter-in-constructor

Comment: через оператор class. я вчера еще узнал ответ, но думал может есть люди, которые мне покажут то, чего я еще не знал)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению или к счастью, это единственный ответ о котором я узнал входе вопроса.

es6:

```
class Foo {
  get a() {
    // getter
  }
  set a(value) {
    // setter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Точно так же, как и снаружи:

```
function Foo() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, {
       get: function() { ... },
       set: function(value) { ... },
    });
}
```

Но если вам не требуется замыкание (например, для "приватных" переменных) - лучше все-таки добавлять свойства прототипу, а не самому объекту:

```
function Foo() {

}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, {
   get: function() { ... },
   set: function(value) { ... },
});
```

Comment: я выше привел пример дескриптора, хоть и не в контексте функции - конструктора. меня интересовал обычный способ на подобии этого:
`var obj = {
    get name() {
        return "Name";
    }
};`